# How to convert string to Uuid in dart

Tags: dart

Is there any thing in dart that has similar functionally to java or C# to convert a string to a Uuid for example something like:

```
Uuid test = Uuid.parse('797ff043-11eb-11e1-80d6-510998755d10');
```

or

```
Uuid test = Uuid.FromString('79700043-11eb-1101-80d6-510900000d10');
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this package can be helpful for you https://pub.dev/packages/uuid

Comment: Thanks I am using this package for Uuid type but the parse method from this package dose not seem to convert to Uuid from sting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) package returns a List object:

```dart
List<int> bytes = Uuid.parse('79700043-11eb-1101-80d6-510900000d10');
```

It doesn't use Uuid as an obtainable object but an "Universally Unique IDentifier" (UUID) as a string or as a byte array.

Comment: Ah okay, I see thanks for clarifying that, I was essentially copying a model from C# that had Guid type fields so in the case of Dart these should just either be of type string. Thanks.

Comment: So in short 'package:uuid/uuid.dart'; will never parse a string to return a Uuid?